# How to add style to parent div when children divs have specific className

Tags: html, css, sass

In mu angular project, I have simple divs like

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
        div1
    </div>
    <div class="child2 green">
        div2
    </div>
</div>

.green {
  background-color:green
}
```

You could see that div2 has background color green(it is added dynamically from a third-party plugin), how could I write scss code to make the div1 also shows green when div2 has the class 'green', is it possile?

Comment: This can be done via JavaScript. In CSS, maybe when `:has` is compatible. https://caniuse.com/css-has

Comment: so,there is no way so far